# Glassfish 4 doesn't start with Eclipse Mars server, user/pass error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, glassfish, glassfish-4

Environment:

- Eclipse Mars
- JDK 8
- Glassfish 4.1
- Windows

I'm getting this error with a new Glassfish 4.1 default server, just by unziping de in to a folder.

[image]

I've tried blank password, admin and admin admin, that they could be the default passwords.

Otherwise, when I directly start the server with **startserv** file from the folder, it starts with no problem.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

The default glassfish password after unzipping the file glassfish-4.1.zip or java_ee_sdk-7u1-web.zip, it seems to be blank. But it is a problem with glassfish plugin in Eclipse that it doesn't work with blank password.

The *solution*, it worked for me, it was to change password through the command **asadmin**.
The file can be found in **yourdirectory\glassfish4\glassfish\bin**, and one it is executed change the password.

```
asadmin> change-admin-password
```

and follow the steps. You'll be prompt for your old password, that in this case was blank.